# .htaccess rewrite / to index.html, all other to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to use .htaccess to rewrite url to my webite:

If url is http://mydomain.com or http://mydomain.com/ the index.html will serve the request, all other urls will go to index.php

please help!

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would internally redirect any request with no path or only a trailing slash to index.html, and everything else to index.php with the path as an argument.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^$ index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite simple, in two rules. One rule for the root (`^$`, which matches the empty string after the leading `REQUEST_URI` slash), and the rest for all other routes (`(.+)`, which matches one or more characters):

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php [L]
```

**Note**: the leading slash does not appear in the source pattern. This is why the first rule checks for an empty string.